# Unknown property cdc

Tags: cassandra

when I set CDC to `true` on a table using `cqlsh` it gives me an error

> Unknown property CDC

do you have any idea how can solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra implemented `CDC` from 3.8 and you should upgrade your Cassandra installation.